# How to change php ini settings for a particular php file

Tags: php, html, web, web-deployment

How can I set custom php ini file for a single php file so that the global settings are not affected?
I want to run a script even after the user closes the connection, but only that script should be running, all others should terminate.

Comment: You may try the ini_set function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: ini_set php can help you with modifying some of the settings. Out of that it is quite up to the server setup which PHP ini will be used.

Comment: @Merianos @Svetoslan in the documentation, it says that `ini_set() Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.` So does it temporarily change the value in the global php settings or just for that script?

Comment: for the whole page

Comment: Just for that script and its includes (which will end up as the same). That is great for setting a temporary time zone or disabling execution time or memory limit and so on. In short: It uses the global config, but overwrites it for the current process.

Comment: @sakshamakagautam the PHP it is initiated every time you make a request for execution. The set of the configurations is set for the whole run time of the given request. I don't know what if you run the `ini_set` at the top of your file, and then before you go out of the file run again the `ini_set` using the previous settings. I have never tried something similar, but maybe it could work.

Comment: This depends on the PHP SAPI and Webserver configuration. Just create a second configuration for that single script and then you have it. Writing that, your question is pretty broad in it's current form and therefore only has comments. I'd suggest to improve the question to make it more clear, e.g. which webserver, operating system, PHP SAPI etc.